# jsf change language of content one by one

Tags: ajax, jsf, primefaces

I hope you can help me with following problem:

I have a  which runs through a list of texts which have several different language-translations (the value is passed by langId which is initially 0). **The Main JSF-Page** looks like:

```
<ui:repeat var="entry" value="#{bean.foundEntries}">
    <ui:include src="../../templates/entryTemplate.xhtml">
        <ui:param name="langId" value="0" />
        <ui:param name="entry" value="#{entry}" />
    </ui:inculde>
</ui:repeat>
```

Now each of the generated Entry has for each available language a button to change the content by clicking on the button. See the **entryTemplate.xhtml**:

```
<ui:composition>
    <table id="whole">
        <tr><td> #{entry.content(langId)} </td></tr>
        <tr><td>
            <ui:repeat var="translation" value="#{entry.translations}">
                <p:commandLink id="button">
                    <p:ajax render=":whole" />
                    //I NEED TO SET/CHANGE SOMEHOW THE passed #{langId} to the new value #{translation.language.id}
                </p:commandLink>
        </td></tr>
    </table>
</ui:composition>
```

I tried with  but it doesn't work.

Is this problem solveable? How can I achieve that the User can change the language of a specific entry by clicking on a button quickly? I tried to avoid saving the language-state of each Entry in the backing bean... or is this the only solution for this?

Thanks for help!

Comment: whoop, where are the comments now?

Answer (score 0):

```
            <h:selectOneMenu id="dropdown" value="#{UtilManagedBean.locale}" onchange="submit()">
                <f:selectItem itemValue="en_US" itemLabel="English" />
                <f:selectItem itemValue="hi_IN" itemLabel="Marathi" />
            </h:selectOneMenu>
```